# New to wordpress: would like to have pluggable main page sections

Tags: plugins, page-template, homepage

I am a long time software developer but quite new to Wordpress. I am hoping I get the terminology right. From my understanding a template in Wordpress determines a page's layout, so I'll use this term in that sense.

I'd like to be able to create a page section of a certain layout (by specifying the section's template I am assuming) and then be able to create a page which is a sequence of these page sections.

For example, you see many "long scroll" websites these days where the main page is built of horizontal sections, each with a different background and layout.

As an example, the website http://whitmansnyc.com/ has these sections in the main page for About, Menu, Press, Locations, Contact Us, Order.

What I am imagining is that each of these sections can be created independently through the Wordpress admin area, and with a certain template specifying its layout (and if the layout/template has room for 3 pictures for example, I'd like those pictures to be specified in their own fields). Then to be able to separately create a page and plug in those sections into the page, e.g. by using some shortcode in the textbox.

Hopefully this is already implemented as part of Wordpress or would be possible to do with some plugin?

I also hope that I could download ready-made templates for the individual page sections as I am not really good at visual design.

Comment: This is in the default theme that comes with 4.7+, and numerous free/premium themes out there, otherwise your question has quite a large scope, and doesn't have a clear concrete formulation. You need to be able to mark an answer as the correct answer, the defacto definitive way to do it, not just the best answer of varying degrees

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The twentyseventeen theme (I assume that is the one you were referrign to) has a set number of sections it seems (4 sections), and you cannot have more it seems. I am looking for a solution which is more general and can work with any theme hopefully. i.e. a way to create individual sections through the admin area and then sequence them one after the other (again, through the admin area), and do that with any theme.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, as a first suggestion, to create custom templates, look to creating a child theme.  There are many many tutorials and discussions on this.

Second, I wonder if the new WordPress Twenty Seventeen theme fits the site structure you're describing?  http://2017.wordpress.net/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is a nice theme , though i was hoping for a way to do it which would work with any theme. Hopefully I elucidated my requirements clearly.

Comment: You really are looking for a theme that will have these elements and provide the back-end options to set these up.  You could develop your own child theme to do this.  However, a quick look at the source code for your noted whitmansnyc site reveals they are using the Himalayas WordPress theme.  I would start there if you are new to WordPress.  Bonus is the theme developer appears to have a nice set of active forums for their themes where you can ask theme-related questions.